# Mapreduce custom formats. Are there lot of circumstance in real world to write custom input and output formats?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know Hadoop supports various input and output formats like Text, Json, Avo, Sequence files etc.

In the real world of Hadoop, do we come across situations where custom input and output formats have to developed by developers.
sorry new to Hadoop world.

thanks much
nath

Comment: Please check my answer.. generally its used to customize the input split..

Comment: I just did Ram. Very kind of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CustomInputFormat can be written when you need to customize input
> record reading..
>
> see below example of CustomInputFormat  out of many such...

***Example : Reading Paragraphs as Input Records***

If you are working on Hadoop MapReduce or Using AWS EMR then there might be an use case where input files consistent a paragraph as key-value record instead of a single line (think about scenarios like analyzing comments of news articles). So instead of processing a single line as input if you need to process a complete paragraph at once as a single record then you will need to customize the default behavior of `**TextInputFormat**` i.e. to read each line by default into reading a complete paragraph as one input key-value pair for further processing in MapReduce jobs.

This requires us to to create a custom record reader which can be done by implementing the `class RecordReader`. The `next()` method is where you would tell the record reader to fetch a paragraph instead of one line. See the following implementation, it’s self-explanatory:

```
public class ParagraphRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
private LineRecordReader lineRecord;
private LongWritable lineKey;
private Text lineValue;
public ParagraphRecordReader(JobConf conf, FileSplit split) throws IOException {
lineRecord = new LineRecordReader(conf, split);
lineKey = lineRecord.createKey();
lineValue = lineRecord.createValue();
}
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
lineRecord.close();
}
@Override
public LongWritable createKey() {
return new LongWritable();

}
@Override
public Text createValue() {
return new Text("");    
}
@Override
public float getProgress() throws IOException {
return lineRecord.getPos();    
}

@Override
public synchronized boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
boolean appended, isNextLineAvailable;
boolean retval;
byte space[] = {' '};
value.clear();
isNextLineAvailable = false;
do {
appended = false;
retval = lineRecord.next(lineKey, lineValue);
if (retval) {
if (lineValue.toString().length() > 0) {
byte[] rawline = lineValue.getBytes();
int rawlinelen = lineValue.getLength();
value.append(rawline, 0, rawlinelen);
value.append(space, 0, 1);
appended = true;
}
isNextLineAvailable = true;
}
} while (appended);

return isNextLineAvailable;
}

@Override
public long getPos() throws IOException {
return lineRecord.getPos();
}
}
```

With a ParagraphRecordReader implementation, we would need to extend TextInputFormat to create a custom InputFomat by just overriding the getRecordReader method and return an object of ParagraphRecordReader to override default behavior.

`ParagrapghInputFormat` will look like:

```
public class ParagrapghInputFormat extends TextInputFormat
{
@Override
public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf conf, Reporter reporter)throws IOException {
reporter.setStatus(split.toString());
return new ParagraphRecordReader(conf, (FileSplit)split);
}
}
```

Ensure that the job configuration to use our custom input format implementation for reading data into MapReduce jobs. It will be as simple as setting up inputformat type to ParagraphInputFormat as show below:

**`conf.setInputFormat(ParagraphInputFormat.class);`**

With above changes, we can read paragraphs as input records into MapReduce programs.

let’s assume that input file is as follows with paragraphs:

And a simple mapper code would look like:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
throws IOException {
System.out.println(key+" : "+value);
}
```

Comment: RamPrasad, Thanks much. New to Hadoop. This will be a good sample for me to work on.

Comment: RamPrasad, do you have a sample dataset for this example. I would like to implement this custom paragraph format

Comment: pastebin.com/dNgjDwra   I am guessing that is the sample data. Right Ram?